# unable to replace raw loop in function template

Tags: c++, c++20

A very fundamental problem while I am learning templates. I am writing a function template returns the sum of array elements.
Here is my snippets.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> T sum(T *pArr, int length)
{
    T ret = pArr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i ++)
            ret += pArr[i];

    return ret;
}

int main(void) {
        int int_data[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
        float float_data[5] = {0.3, 0.44, 0.666, 0.213, 0.498};
        int i = 0;
        // print sum of 5 integers
        std::cout << "\nSum of above is :: " << sum(int_data, 5) << std::endl;

        // print sum of 5 float numbers
        std::cout << "\nSum of above is :: " << sum(float_data, 5) << std::endl;

        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible to replace the raw loop with range-based loop? My understanding is that, if we are not doing arithmetic against a given collection then this is impossible.
2. If it is possible to replace the raw loop. What would be the modern versions? C++14, 17, 20 ?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with templates

Comment: You should look at how range based for loop work. There are many SO questions on the subject. Once you understand that, you should have your answer

Comment: What else do you want to "replace the raw loop" with? `std::accumulate()` comes to mind here if you will entertain iterator-based solutions.

Comment: @user253751 I do think template matters. Suppose I pass `std::vector` as the argument for `T sum()` . How shall I correctly call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass array by reference (or object as `std::span`), you might use for range:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
T sum(const T (&arr)[N])
{
    T ret{};
    for (auto& e : arr) {
         ret += e;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

or

```
template <class T, std::size_t Size>
auto sum(const std::span<T, Size>& arr)
{
    std::remove_const_t<T> ret{};

    for (auto& e : arr) {
         ret += e;
    }
    return ret;
}

template <class Container>
auto sum(const Container& arr)
-> decltype(::sum(std::span(arr)))
{
    return ::sum(std::span(arr));
}
```

and `main` becomes:

```
int main()
{
    const int int_data[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    float float_data[5] = {0.3, 0.44, 0.666, 0.213, 0.498};
    // print sum of 5 integers
    std::cout << "\nSum of above is :: " << sum(int_data) << std::endl;

    // print sum of 5 float numbers
    std::cout << "\nSum of above is :: " << sum(float_data) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TKxjf3)

Comment: Yeah, or const reference to `std::array`, or if variable size and owning then `std::vector`, or any other usual way to store a bunch of numbers.

Comment: @underscore_d   I like your suggestion. I did try to use it in std::vector inside by replacing with const std::vector<int> int_data and std::vector<float> float_data . However I am not sure what to modify inside the template definition, i.e. sum(?). I heard I have to create a struc but not sure it is really necessary. If you could provide an answer that would be perfect.

Comment: @Jarod42, like your second suggestion, but there seem to be an error in the 2nd suggestion with use of `std::span` and it does not seem to compile. (under c++20 with all relevant libraries)

Comment: Indeed, some deduction cannot be resolved automatically, need to add extra layer: demo link added.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <numeric>
#include <span>
#include <type_traits>
```

In C++20, you could do:

```
template<class T> T sum1(T *pArr, int length)
{
    if (!length) return {};
    auto sum = pArr[0];
    for (auto const &elem : std::span(pArr+1, length-1))
      sum += elem;
    return sum;
}
```

But then, you might wish to use `std::accumulate` anyway:

```
template<class T> T sum2(T *pArr, int length)
{
    if (!length) return {};
    return std::accumulate(pArr+1, pArr+length, pArr[0]);
}
```

And then, the pointer interface is atrocious. How about:

```
template <class Range> auto sum3(Range &&range)
{
    auto const b = std::begin(range), e = std::end(range);
    if (b == e) return std::decay_t<decltype(*b)>{};
    return std::accumulate(std::next(b), e, *b);
}
```

And a little test:

```
int main()
{
    auto const expected_sum = 6;
    const std::array<int, 3> data {1, 2, 3};
    auto const N = data.size();
    assert(sum1(&data[0], N) == expected_sum);
    assert(sum2(&data[0], N) == expected_sum);
    assert(sum3(data) == expected_sum);
}
```

All of the above could be constexpr as well, with `static_assert`, AFAIK :)

Comment: The three argument overload of `std::accumulate` uses `+`, you don't need `add` (a.k.a. `std::plus<T>{}`)

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove the loop would be to use C++ 17 fold expression. [Try on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/P54rr3):

```
template<typename T, size_t length, size_t... Idx>
constexpr T sum_impl(const T (&arr)[length], std::index_sequence<Idx...>)
{
    return (0 + ... + arr[Idx]);
}


template<typename T, size_t length>
constexpr T sum(const T (&arr)[length])
{
    return sum_impl<T, length>(arr, std::make_index_sequence<length>{});
}

//for vectors etc, not really necessary as you can just directly use
//std::accumulate which is simpler and better I think.
template<typename Container>
typename Container::value_type _sum(const Container& v)
{
    using ValueType = typename Container::value_type;
    return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), static_cast<ValueType>(0));
}

//usage
int main()
{
    float float_data[5] = {0.3, 0.44, 0.666, 0.213, 0.498};
    constexpr int int_data[5] = {1,2,3,4,8};
    //compile time
    static_assert(sum(int_data) == 18);
    std::cout << sum(int_data) << '\n';
    std::cout << sum(float_data);

    //vectors
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::cout << '\n' << sum(v);
    std::vector<float> f {0.3, 0.2, 0.3};
    std::cout << '\n' << sum(f);
}
```